# Find and extract the name of xml tag if specific attribute is matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to extract the name of the tag `column` if that column tag has `(group)` string in `name` attribute. I researched through the stack and I found some hints, but I'm not getting an answer by following these. More information is given below.

EXAMPLE XML:

```
<datas>
    <data>
      <column datatype='real' default-format='c&quot;$&quot;#,##0;(&quot;$&quot;#,##0)' name='[Sales]' role='measure' type='quantitative' />
      <column datatype='real' default-format='c&quot;$&quot;#,##0;(&quot;$&quot;#,##0)' name='[Shipping Cost]' role='measure' type='quantitative' />
      <column datatype='string' name='[State]' role='dimension' semantic-role='[State].[Name]' type='nominal' />
      <column datatype='string' name='[Sub-Category (group)]' role='dimension' type='nominal'>
    </data>
</datas>
```

MY TRY:

```
#USING ELEMTREE, python3 to parse xml
columnfind = twbroot.findall('./datas/data')
for i in columnfind:
    select= i.("//*[contains(@name,'(group)')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.etree` module only supports [limited subset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) of XPath 1.0, which doesn't include `contains()`. So you'll need to do the 'contains' check in python:

```
columnfind = twbroot.findall('data/column')
for col in columnfind:
    if '(group)' in col.get('name'):
        print col.get('name')
```

or alternatively :

```
cols = [e.get('name') for e in root.findall("data/column") if '(group)' in e.get('name')]
print(cols)
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/963451)</kbd>**

If you can afford to use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/), it has full XPath 1.0 support, so you'll be able to do the check in XPath directly :

```
cols = [e.get('name') for e in root.xpath("data/column[contains(@name,'(group)')]")]
print(cols)
```

Comment: tq @har07 , instead of your olumnfind, i used :  columnfind = twbroot.iter('column')